# Existence of a certain smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given an $\varepsilon > 0$, does there exists an $\eta \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ such that $\eta(x) = 1$ for $|x| \leq 1 - \varepsilon$, $\eta(x) = 0$ for $|x| \geq 1$ and $|\nabla \eta(x)| \leq c/\varepsilon^{2}$ for some constant $c$ on $1 - \varepsilon \leq |x| \leq 1$?

Comment: Your function can't even be continuous, since $\eta(1 + \frac{1}{n})=1 \to 1 \neq 0 = \eta(lim(1 + \frac{1}{n})) = \eta(1)=0$

Comment: Why would $\eta(1 + 1/n) = 1$? It should be $ = 0$.

Comment: oops, $\eta(1 - \frac{1}{n})$ sorry. I mean your constraints imply clearly to be discontinuous at $x=1$ and $x=-1$

Comment: I don't think so, the $\epsilon$ is so that my function decays sufficiently enough to not have a discontinuity at $x = \pm 1$. So if I change my condition to $|\nabla \eta(x)| \leq c/\epsilon$ instead, then from Stein's Real Analysis book, page 236: Let $\chi$ be a fixed $C^{2}$ function on $[0, 1]$ that equals 1 on $[0, 1/4]$ and equals $0$ on $[3/4, 1]$. Then let $\eta = \chi((|x| - 1 + \epsilon)/\epsilon)$ and $\eta$ satisfies the decary conditions.

Comment: If $\eta$ satisfies the first two conditions, doesn't $c=\sup\left\{\Vert\nabla\eta(x)\Vert:|x|\leq 1\right\}\varepsilon^2$ work?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro $c$ should be independent of $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can even have better control: $|\nabla \eta|\le c/\epsilon$.

It suffices to construct such a function $\eta$ in $d=1$; in higher dimensions just take $\eta(|x|)$.

Take a smooth function $\psi$ with integral $1$, supported in $[-1/2,1/2]$. Let $M$  be the supremum of $| \psi'|$. The rescaled function $\psi_\epsilon(x) =  \epsilon^{-1} \psi(x/\epsilon)$ also has integral $1$, and $|\psi_\epsilon'|\le M/\epsilon^2$.

Convolve the characteristic function $\chi$ of the interval $[-1+1/(2\epsilon), 1-1/(2\epsilon)]$ with $\psi_{\epsilon}$. You'll get a function $\eta$ with the  desired behaviour: $1$ on $[-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$, $0$ outside of $[-1,1]$.

A bound on $|\eta'|$ is given by the convolution of $|\psi_\epsilon'|$ with $\chi$. We have 
$$\sup |\chi*\psi_\epsilon'|\le \|\chi\|_\infty \|\psi_\epsilon'\|_1 \le c/\epsilon$$